# proving function spaces as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in upper division linear algebra, and i need help in proving a function space as a vector space. I just need help proving 2 particular vector space axioms.

Axiom 1: There exists an element in V denoted by 0 such that x+0=x for each x in V

Axiom 2:For each element x in V there exists an element y in V such that x+y=0

Note: V stands for vector space

For proving the first axiom, would you say: let f be a member of V. therefore f(s+0)= f(s)+f(0)=f(s)

As for the second axiom, I have no idea how to start the proof....

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: The identity element of the addition on $V$ could be the $0$ function, which has the range of $\{0\}$. 

Addition is usually defined point-wise, that is $(f+g)(x) := f(x) + g(x)$, where $x \in \operatorname{dom}f \cap \operatorname{dom}g$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first axiom you can take the function $f=0$; for the second, given $f$ in your space you can consider $-f$ and the sum is $0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! So, would this proof work?                                      f(s)+ -f(s)= 0?

Comment: This is $f(s)+ (-f(s))=f(s)-f(s)=0$ because f(s)=f(s) as vectors (or numbers, or whatever they are, it depends on the functions).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing functions and their arguments. Your vector space are the functions themselves. Presumably, addition of functions $f$ and $g$ is defined as $h=f+g$ where $h(x):= f(x)+g(x)$.

So for the first axiom, the "zero function" (constant function that is zero everywhere) works. For the second axiom, consider the function $-f$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment! So, would this proof work? f(s)+ -f(s)= 0?